# How to run a .txt with an .exe using python? ("dragging" .txt into .exe)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, os.path

Me and my friend are trying to make a small program and we need to be able to do the same as if you would be dragging the .txt into the .exe, but with python.

The .exe is a converter which we need in order to read the .txt file.
We already can choose the file, but I couldn't find anything about how to run 2 files together.

I hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you drag a file into an executable, its pathname is passed as the first command-line argument (see `sys.argv`).

Depending on how your Windows environment is configured, the `.py` file type may already be marked in a way that lets you drag other files onto them in File Explorer, so you'll end up with the Python interpreter running the script with the dragged file's pathname in `sys.argv`.

If that's not the case, you can use e.g. https://www.pyinstaller.org/ or https://github.com/indygreg/PyOxidizer or https://www.py2exe.org/ to make an .exe out of your Python script with which the drag-and-drop functionality will certainly work.

Comment: It's like this though:    I have a window and a button. I choose the .txt and then I want it to be converted without dragging anything.

Comment: In that case, just look at the `subprocess` module to run other programs. E. G. `subprocess.check_call(['path/to/converter.exe', file_to_convert])`